# Задать breakpoints in code

Tags: javascript

Привет.
Кто поскажет ключевое слово для создание breakpoints при загрузке страниц.
Требуется,чтобы при загрузке страници код остановился на строчке на которой указано ключевое слово.
Я где-то видел но забыл.Прошу напомнить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debugger

http://jsfiddle.net/bjApL/

```
console.log("а сейчас мы остановимся");
debugger
console.log("done");
```

будет работать только если консоль открыта.

Comment: Очень благодарен...